# How to make a for loop which can check/edit multiple VB.net TextBoxes

Tags: vb.net, winforms

For instance I have 5 textboxes in VB designer with different names
TextBox1, TextBox2 .... TextBox5

Is there any simple way to load/check the TextBox1, 2 ...5, by using 1 line recursively?

I am trying to load the textboxes with a list of list data structure. 
So every time I have to put a TextBox(number).Text to load it.

```
Private Sub addbutton_click() handles addbutton.click
  TextBox1.Text=MyList1(Some_constant)(other_constant).Name(0)
  TextBox2.Text=MyList1(Some_constant)(other_constant).Name(1)
End Sub
```

I want to use a for loop which should look something like this so that I can iterate over the Name(0), (1) and the TextBox(number).Text. I am not able to iterate over the TextBox(number) as the textBox is a VB tool item.

```
Private Sub addbutton_click() handles addbutton.click
   For i As Integer = 0 to 5
       TextBox(i).Text = MyList1(Some_constant)(other_constant).Name(i)
   Next i 
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to put them in a list yourself. Or put them in some sort of panel and loop the controls inside that panel.

Comment: @the_lotus thanks! I put the TextBoxes in an array of type TextBox which worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your index values into the `Tag` property of the TextBox. 
Loop through the controls when you need to do your recursive processing:

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try

            'get your list of text boxes
            For Each tb As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
                Dim indexValue As Integer
                'get your index value out the tag
                Integer.TryParse(tb.Tag, indexValue)
                'use it
                tb.Text = MyList1(Some_constant)(other_constant).Name(indexValue)
            Next

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An exception occurred: ", ex.Message))
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Nice answer! Though you should remove the `ToList` call and just iterate `Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)`. Making it a list is just unnecessary processing and extra memory. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent thanks! I've amended it as suggested. Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer Thanks for the answer! I also wanted to iterate over different textboxes with different names, I tried multiple things with the tag property. Sorry if my question was unclear. This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21083208/8047266